# Load local HTML into WebView

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can I load a local HTML file (with images and ...) into a `WebView`?
Just setting the `Source` parameter does not do the trick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can load it from a file as long as the file is part of the app package, e.g.:

```
WebView2.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///assets/text.html");
```

From [WebView.Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate.aspx)

> WebView can load content from the application’s package using
>   ms-appx-web://, from the network using http/https, or from a string
>   using NavigateToString. It cannot load content from the application’s
>   data storage. To access the intranet, the corresponding capability
>   must be turned on in the application manifest.

For a 'random' file, I suppose you could prompt user via file picker to select the file then read it into a string and use [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx), but the user experience there may be a bit odd depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't think the quote and the link is a match anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I was working at this problem for a long time and I found a way to do that: 
At first you should save it in **`InstalledLocation`** folder. If you haven't option to create a new .html file you can just use `file.CopyAsync(htmlFolder, fname + ".html");`
 Look into my example:

```
StorageFolder htmlFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.CreateFolderAsync(@"HtmlFiles", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
IStorageFile file = await htmlFolder .CreateFileAsync(fname + ".html", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

and than you can easily open your .html file:

```
var fop = new FileOpenPicker();
fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".html");
var file = await fop.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
   string myPath = file.Path.Substring(file.Path.IndexOf("HtmlFiles"));
   myWebview.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///" + myPath));
}
```

Remember just only from **`InstalledLocation`** you can open it with `ms-appx-web:///`