# WebView2 how to load local file?

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

I have a WebView2 control in my WinForm .NET Framework 4.7.2, how can i load inside it my local html file?

I was trying to set the .Source with file:// extention but nothing...

Here is what i've tryed:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webView.Source = new Uri("file://C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/VisualSelf/self.html");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225796/load-local-html-into-webview

Comment: Others answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417997/display-local-html-file-content-in-uwp-webview

Comment: i've added the html file from desktop to my project but if i try to do : `new Uri("ms-appx-web:///VisualSelf/self.html")` the webView still show nothing

Comment: May you try to load a universal website e.g https://www.microsoft.com?

Comment: @m.r226 no... if i set webView.Source = new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/") it still doesn't show nothing

Comment: @m.r226 even if i set in property the source it's not showing anything

Comment: What about winform webbrowser control?

Comment: @m.r226 i forget to install WebView2 Runtime... that was the problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read HTML file , and then `NavigateToString`

```
if (webView!= null && webView.CoreWebView2 != null)
{
     string text = system.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/VisualSelf/self.html");
     webView.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(text);
}
```

or you can `Navigate` to local file:

```
webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/VisualSelf/self.html");
```

Also, you need to install [Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/).

Comment: I used the Navigate("file:///my.html") method and the webview shows "File not found"

Comment: This will fail if the HTML content is > 2MB, including embedded fonts from Google,